# Inequality regarding norms and weak-star convergence

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence

Let $X$ be a normed space and $(x'_n) \subseteq X'$ a sequence of functionals where $x_n'$ has $x'$ has its limit in the *-weak topology in $X'$. Show that
$$
  ||x'|| \le \operatorname{lim inf}_{n\to \infty} ||x'_n||.
$$
I have no glue how to show this, do you have any hints?

Answer (score 4):

Fix $N$ an integer, and let $v_N$ of norm $1$ such that $\lVert x'(v_N)\rVert\geqslant \lVert x'\rVert -N^{—1}$.

Then write 
$$\lVert x'\rVert\leqslant N^{-1}+\liminf_{n\to +\infty}\lVert x'_n(v_N)\rVert$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $L=\liminf_{n\to\infty}\|x_n\|$.  Consider a subsequence $x_{n_k}'$ so $\|x_{n_k}\|<L+\epsilon$.  This converges to *-weakly $x'$.  By Banach-Alaoglu, $\|x'\|\leq L+\epsilon$.  Of course, $\epsilon$ can be chosen arbitrarily small.  [This is less elementary than the first solution proposed, but can easily be adapted to nets.]

[It is false that $\|x_n'\|\to \|x'\|$, as suggested below.  Consider any orthonormal sequence in an infinite-dimensional Hilbert space, which necessarily *-weakly converges to $0$.]