# $\phi_n \rightarrow \phi$ weakly-$*$, then $\|\phi\|\leq \limsup_n \|\phi_n\|$.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, proof-verification, weak-convergence

> $\phi_n \rightarrow \phi$ weakly-$*$, then $\|\phi\|\leq \limsup_n
>  \|\phi_n\|$.

**My attempt:**

$$\|\phi\| = \sup_{\|x\| = 1} |\phi(x)| \leq \sup_{\|x\| = 1} \lim_n |\phi_n(x)|$$
Using an epsilon-argument, there exists an $x_0$ with norm one such that 
$$\|\phi\| \leq \lim_n |\phi_n(x_0)| + \epsilon$$
then
$$\|\phi\| \leq \limsup_n \sup_{\|x\| = 1} |\phi_n(x)| + \epsilon = \|\phi_n\| + \epsilon.$$

**Question:**
could you please provide an explicit example such that $\phi_n \rightarrow \phi$ weakly-$*$ and
$$\|\phi\| > \liminf \|\phi_n\|.$$
Thank you very much!

**Edit:** For the counter example, $\phi_n$ has to converge weakly-$*$ to something that is not the zero functional. We want
$$\|\phi\| > \liminf \|\phi_n\|,$$
not 
$$\|\phi\| < \liminf \|\phi_n\|.$$

I know $\|\phi\|\leq \liminf \|\phi_n\|$ holds for $\phi_n \rightarrow \phi$ weakly. When the space is not reflexive, weak-$*$ convergence does not imply weak convergence, so I was hoping to find a counter example for this inequality.

Basically, I want to know why the inequality in the problem is a $\limsup$ but not $\liminf$ (which holds for weak convergence).

Comment: Are you sure you want $\|\phi\|>\liminf \|\phi_n\|$? This is not true.

Comment: This inequality is not true. With a little adapatation your proof, you can prove that $\|\phi\|\le \liminf \|\phi_n\|$.

Comment: @Tomás yeah I was wondering about this as well. I know $\|\phi\|\leq \liminf \|\phi_n\|$ holds for $\phi_n \rightarrow \phi$ weakly. When the space is not reflexive, weak-$*$ convergence does not imply weak convergence, so I was hoping to find a counter example for this inequality.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/274764/inequality-regarding-norms-and-weak-star-convergence/274771#274771

Comment: I see, thank you for the link, and I upvoted your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct inequality is $||\phi|| \le \lim \inf ||\phi_n||\ $. $\ $Let's prove it. Let $M = ||\phi||$. Take $\epsilon >0$ arbitrary. There exists $x$ of norm $1$ so that $|\phi(x)| > M -\epsilon$. Since $\phi_n(x)$ converges to $\phi(x)$ we also have $|\phi_n(x)| \to |\phi(x)|$. Therefore $|\phi_n(x)|> M-\epsilon$ for $n$ large enough. But $||\phi_n|| \ge |\phi_n(x)|$ since $||x||=1$.
We conclude that $||\phi_n|| > M-\epsilon$ for $n$ large enough and therefore $\lim \inf ||\phi_n|| \ge M -\epsilon$. Since $\epsilon > 0$ was arbitrary we conclude
$\lim \inf ||\phi_n|| \ge M$ that is 
$$\lim \inf ||\phi_n|| \ge ||\phi||$$
This inequality can be strict. Consider an infinite dimensional Hilbert space. A Hilbert space is self dual so we may consider vectors instead of functionals. Let $(\phi_n)$ an orthonormal system. Then $\phi_n \to 0$ weakly and $||\phi_n|| = 1$ for all $n$.

Also, $\phi_n + \phi_0 \to \phi_0$ weakly and $||\phi_n + \phi_0 ||= \sqrt{2}$, $||\phi_0|| =1$.

Comment: How can $0>1$.?

Comment: orangeskid presumably wanted to give a counterexample to the *correct* version of the inequality.

Comment: just added a complete proof of the correct statement.

Answer (score 2):

I guess that the OP meant:

$$\|\phi\| \leqslant \liminf_{n\to\infty}\|\phi_n\|,$$

which is [always true](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/274764/inequality-regarding-norms-and-weak-star-convergence). The inequality can be however strict.

Take $(\phi_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ to be the canonical basis of $\ell_2 = \ell_2^*$. It converges weak* to 0 but it consists of unit vectors. A similar situation takes place in dual spaces of all infinite dimensional Banach spaces; this is the famous Josefson–Nissenzweig theorem:

> If $X$ is an infinite-dimensional Banach space, then there exists a sequence $(\phi_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ of unit vectors in $X^*$ which converges to 0 weak*.

For the references, see

> B. Josefson, [Weak sequential convergence in the dual of a Banach space does not imply norm convergence](http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1975-81-01/S0002-9904-1975-13691-3/S0002-9904-1975-13691-3.pdf), *Ark. Mat.* **13** (1975), 79–89.
>
> A. Nissenzweig, [$w^*$ sequential convergence](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF02761594#page-1), *Israel J. Math*. **22** (1975), 266–272.